# Get string between two strings if list of strings is not inside

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Hope the title wasn't too confusing.

I have a directory full of files which contain stories. I need to get a list of strings that are between two sentences (always forward) only if the string between them does not contain any of the sentences contained in another list. Per story.

So for example, I have a list "The big dog", "she went after him", Anne bit her lip", etc.

Then I have a file, which may be a story containing who knows what. And I want to find the string between "He leapt after her" and "She kissed him" but only if the string between them does not contain any of the sentences in the first list, or themselves.

I have found a few ways to do it but most are so slow it takes almost an hour to do a file, I am sure there must be better and faster ways to do it. Note I did not add it here because I didn't want to limit solutions to what I am doing which is probably not the best way.

Comment: CAn you show us the methods, or at least explain us what methods did you try?

Comment: Why is it a problem that it takes an hour to do a file? How many files are there? And at what rate are you getting new files, or at what rate are the inputs (such as the word lists) changing? What kind of turnaround time do you need, and what is the real-world requirement which dictates it (other than just "I wanna see the computer go fast"). :)

Comment: It is a program to check students work for following the rules set forth that week, and also check for plagerism. So it has to be usable for a teacher to do over 100 files in an evening. This is only one small part of the program but an important one, as there are many other steps involved it does need to do each file as quickly as possible.

Comment: I have used regex to find a single string contained between two strings, but when I add a loop to check to be sure that the captured string does not contain the list of sentences, it becomes very slow. I am sure there is a faster way to feed it the list of sentences and do the checking at the same time with Linq but I am not very good at linq. Also note, that the list of nono sentences can be extremely long.Containing everything from "catch phrases" they are not supposed to use to slang terms. Well over 1k entries, but the list will not change while the files are being checked.

Comment: The methods are going to be messy and slow for this type of scenario. Without looking at the methods themselves, it's hard to say if they can be improved, but my recommendation would be to load the entire dataset of stories/sentences within stories and then thread the find tasks to improve speed.

Comment: In lieu of regex, would using String.Contains help matters?  You might need to do a little work to accommodate case-insensitivity -- e.g., convert the target string to upper case, or write an appropriate extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what is the algorithm you are using to solve the problem you describe, but this what i'll do in such situation

**Pre-Process:**

- Make sure any sequence of blank characters is reduce to one (spaces, tabs, etc).
- Make the whole text either lower or upper case.

**Process:**

- Preload all the flagged words to memory (ordered list to use binary search, in theory this process should only consume time the first time you create the list, proceed to order the entries and persist these in a format that you can load later on, any further additions should do a binary search to determine if the word is in the list and place the entry in the corresponding position/slot).
- Preload all catch phrases to memory (Here we can use the same approach that we use for loading the words).
- Wall through the file and keep the offset/position and length of any word that matches the flagged list. The offset should be a long just to take into account large files.
- Find sequences of flagged words. Any match after the first word is a candidate for a sequence, since we remove all sequence of blank characters we are certain that WordN is part of a sequence if the Offset of this word is equals to the offset of the previous word plus the previous word length plus 1, the 1 here represents the blank character that separators the two words. word2Offset = word1Offset + word1Length + 1.
- Check if any of the sequences found matches starts or matches the catch phrases.

**Implementation Assets:**

- **Word:** a simple String will suffice to represent the words. All words must be store in either lower or upper case.
- **Component:** a component is an structure which holds a word and the offset of a file where it was found in the file
- **Phrase:** is Composition of two or more components, a simple list will be enough.
- Reading the file one character at the time can help to quickly determine the words and sequences of words. For instance, every blank space means a new component is was read, basically a word, so we can use check right there if it matches or not, if it matches and is the first match, we don't know if it is part of a sequence, but once we are read the second or third word and we know if matches we can check if the current offset is follows the rules we describe earlier.

**Checking for phases**

- If no words flagged, no phrases will match. Almost impossible, but who knows.
- Any sequence of word matches in the file represents a candidate for phrases checking.
- Check word length and later word contents to check for matches between the catch phrase and candidate. Here you can check either if part or the whole phrase matches.

**Getting the text between two sequence phases.**

Since the phase is just a list of components we just need to read the file from the sum of offset and length of the last word of the first phrase to the offset of the first word of the second phrase.

From = PhaseALastWordOffset + PhaseALastWordLength
To = PhaseBFirstWordOffset
Contents = StoryFile.readSegment(From, To);

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why read it one at a time like this instead of simply splitting on periods then looping through them? Just trying to learn more.

Comment: If you loop through all files you are retaining the data about all of them in memory at the same time, causing performance problems. Also is easier to recover from processing one file and resume from that file forward, than having to restart the process from scratch cause you work all files at once. In term of reading the whole file, it is wiser to read by chunks, same principle of saving resources. you can either go with reading N chars/bytes or read one at the time, but i wont go with reading the whole file. Remember you need a buffer to retain the contents.